# Search uses * in database as a wildcard

Tags: c#, search, wildcard, reverse

I have a database of vin numbers for vehicles.

Some have `*` as a character as it could be any number or letter. however some are specific.

E.g.

```
VF1***HFX**8*****
```

I am now looking for a string that would allow `*` in the table to be a wildcard.

E.g. if someone searched `Tusk` or `Task` it would find `T*sk` in the database.

In C#

Comment: Start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For that kind of inverted wildcard use, I think you would have to write your own comparer for each element in the DB as you are not comparing your search string against the DB data, but the DB data against your search string.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way of searching entry and * on every character entry within the search box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what SQL server you're on, but hopefully this works on any (tested on MSSQL).

If you look at the documentation for [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), you see that the wildcard you need is `_` (underscore). Operators in SQL, in general, can be used both ways (i.e. both `field LIKE constant` and `constant LIKE field` will work). So, without knowing you table structure (which would have been quite helpful actually), your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE 'V123456789' LIKE REPLACE(Vehicles.Vin,'*','_')
```

I'm not sure about the performance here, but hopefully this should get you started in the right direction.